# JQuery does not work using computer name under Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, url, internet-explorer-11, hostname, windows-server-2012-r2

I have following MasterPage code of ASP.NET WebForm app.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css") %> " rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css") %> " rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css") %>  " rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Content/reports.css") %> " rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") %>"></script>
    <%--<script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/moment.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/es.js") %>"></script>
    <script src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/reports.js") %>"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formMain" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have code for `Bootstrap Datatimepicker`

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'es',
        maxDate: 'now',
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });
});
```

All this code works just fine when i use IP address of the host like

```
http://10.1.5.34/MyWebsite/Report1
```

But when I use computer name it does not work

```
http://MyPCName/MyWebsite/Report1
```

I cannot see any errors but what is strange that Chrome displays all things properly under `http://MyPCName/MyWebsite/Report1`

So it has something to do with IE 11...

I have now clue how to fix it. Any clue?

Comment: does it matches to the hostname or hostname -f ( with domain ) output ?

Comment: @IndraUprade Sorry, what do u mean?

Comment: Ignore if you have already tried hostname with domain info. I meant to say is hostname in url is matching with output of hostname command ?

Comment: @IndraUprade Yes it is.

Comment: or u on mac or windows

Comment: @IndraUprade I am on Windows-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related to [Compatibility View and "Smart Defaults"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults/).

IE uses different `Browser Mode` or `Document Mode` between the two instances.

You can force IE to use the same mode by  setting the registry value or adding this to the page header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```